# I'm trying to add some script to my google sheets display various gifs in a sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to display a different html page with a different gif (7 in total) depending on the value of a cell in a sheet. When my students scan their qr code (to record their attendance) a particular cell ranges between 1-15 and I want to have that number call a different gif in the sidebar. I was able to display a sidebar with a gif but I don't know how to make the html page change depending on the value in the cell. So far I have 2 html pages with different gifs but I was planning to have seven and use nested if statements to call different pages.
I included the script below as javascript because I couldn't see the google apps script option.Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar () {
 var htmlA = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('tomato')
 var htmlB = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('cucumber')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
var cellValueRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("H2"); 
var cellValue = cellValueRange.getValue();
if(cellValue = 1){
.showSidebar(htmlA);}
else if(cellValue = 2){
.showSidebar(htmlB);}
     
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
 <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/kDwLZpqtiTObyo4qc8/giphy.gif"> <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />

<style> 

body{
background-image:url("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v0uW1hxmCwGhjnInIiXwempyorFHFo07/view?usp=sharing")
}
</style>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to extend your script from 2 pages to 7 pages, for example, how about using JSON object like ``var pages = {"1": "tomato", "2": "cucumber",,,}``? Using this, the HTML file can be changed by ``var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(pages[value])``, where ``value`` is the value of cell. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.  My question might be confusing because I don't really understand how to achieve what I want. I thought of another approach where I might use a separate js file to simply modify the gif URL depending on the value. But anyway, I'll try your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your case, the URL of gif is ``https://media.giphy.com/media/kDwLZpqtiTObyo4qc8/giphy.gif``, and you have 7 URLs. You want to change the URL by the value. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that is right.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script, ``htmlB`` has ``setTitle('My custom sidebar').setWidth(200)``. But ``htmlA`` has no them. How about this?

Comment: Yes it should be the same. i don't know how to set out the script correctly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a modified script. At first, please confirm whether my understanding for your question is correct. And could you please confirm about the script? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have 7 URLs of the gif images.
- You want to extend your script from 2 pages to 7 pages.
- You want to change the URL of gif images by the value from "H2" of "Sheet1" in the Spreadsheet.
- You want to use the same HTML style.

  - In your script, `htmlA` and `htmlB` are different. But you want to use the same HTML.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, I used Templated HTML. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### HTML&Javascript side:

From:

```
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/kDwLZpqtiTObyo4qc8/giphy.gif">
```

To:

```
<img src="<?= url ?>">
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify `showSidebarss()` as follows. Before you run the script, please do the following settings.

- Set URLs of images to `gifImages`.
- Set the filename of HTML to `var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');`.

Modified script:

```
function showSidebarss() {
  // Please set URLs of gif images.
  var gifImages = {
    "1": "https://media.giphy.com/media/kDwLZpqtiTObyo4qc8/giphy.gif",
    "2": "### URL for value 2 ###",
    "3": "### URL for value 3 ###",
    ,
    ,
    ,
  };

  // Retrieve value as a key.
  var cellValueRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("H2"); 
  var cellValue = cellValueRange.getValue();

  // Show sidebar.
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index'); // Please set this.
  html.url = gifImages[cellValue.toString()]; // Set url for <?= url ?>.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html.evaluate());
}
```

- The script might work even if `toString()` of `cellValue.toString()` is removed.

#### Note:

- This is a simple modification. So please modify it for your situation.

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

### Edit:

If you want to run `showSidebarss()` when you edited the cell of "H2" of "Sheet1", please modify as follows.

Before you use this script. Please install the OnEdit trigger to `showSidebarss()` as follows.

#### How to install OnEdit trigger:

- Open the script editor.

  - Edit -> Current project's triggers.
  - Click "Add Trigger".
  - Set "showSidebarss" for "Choose which function to run".
  - Set "From spreadsheet" for "Select event source".
  - Set "On edit" for "Select event type".

After install the trigger, when you edit the cell of "H2" of "Sheet1", `showSidebarss()` is automatically run.

#### Modified script:

```
function showSidebarss(e) {
  if (e && e.source.getSheetName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.getA1Notation() == "H2") {
    // Please set URLs of gif images.
    var gifImages = {
      "1": "https://media.giphy.com/media/kDwLZpqtiTObyo4qc8/giphy.gif",
      "2": "### URL for value 2 ###",
      "3": "### URL for value 3 ###",
      ,
      ,
      ,
    };

    // Retrieve value as a key.
    var cellValueRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("H2"); 
    var cellValue = cellValueRange.getValue();

    // Show sidebar.
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index'); // Please set this.
    html.url = gifImages[cellValue.toString()]; // Set url for <?= url ?>.
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html.evaluate());
  }
}
```

#### Note

- In the current stage, there are no methods for changing HTML of the sidebar, which has already been opened, using Google Apps Script. So as a workaround, I used the method for changing HTML by overwriting the sidebar.

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Wow! It's almost perfect. Thankyou!. The only problem is that I have to refresh the screen and click the custom menu>sidebar tab to get it to change. Is it possible to change it by changing the value only?

Comment: The only problem is that I have to click the custom menu>sidebar tab to get the gif to change. Is it possible to change the gif instantly by changing the value?

Comment: @nick Thank you for replying. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @nick In the current stage, there are no methods for changing HTML of the sidebar, which has already been opened, using Google Apps Script. So as a workaround, I used the method for changing HTML by overwriting the sidebar. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: thank you for your help. I followed your instructions. When I click on the 'custom menu'>'show sidebar' from the top menu the script runs and finishes and the sidebar does not show up.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike, you've been incredibly helpful.

Comment: @nick I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.